# foreign key relation constraint - cascade on update also the other value of the foreign id

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

**INITIAL STATE**

```
parents
id    parent_validity
1     1
2     1

children
id    parent_id    child_validity
1     1            1
2     1            1
3     2            1
```

**REQUIRED STATE AFTER UPDATE**

```
parents
id    parent_validity
1     0 (updated as 0)
2     1

children
id    parent_id    child_validity
1     1            0 (This val is expected as 0)
2     1            0 (This val is expected as 0)
3     2            1 (This val is expected as no change)
```

**WHAT I GOT**

```
children
id    parent_id    child_validity
1     1            0
2     1            0
3     2            0 (all values under this column became 0)
```

What I want is if I update a `parent_validity` in table `parents`, then related `child_validity` in table `children` should be updated. What I mean from *related* is foreign key relationship of `id`s.

My result is: Any validity change in table `parents` changes **all validities** in table `children`.

I don't want to do what I required with PHP. let MySQL handles.

I couldn't get the correct search terms for my request in web so I was unable to find any solution. Can you please help me.

Thanks for your help.

note: I think my q title needs an update. (That was my best, sorry.)

**my sql to create and give the constraints**

```
CREATE TABLE `parents` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_validity` bit(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1:valid or 0:invalid',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY (`parent_validity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `children` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `child_validity` bit(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1:valid or 0:invalid',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY (`child_validity`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)  REFERENCES parents(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_parent_validity FOREIGN KEY (child_validity)  REFERENCES parents(parent_validity) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is a composite key, but you should evaluate the design impact this entails for your solution:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `children`, `parents`; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `parents` (
    ->   `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `parent_validity` bit(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1:valid or 0:invalid',  
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `parent_validity`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `children` (
    ->   `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `parent_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `child_validity` bit(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1:valid or 0:invalid',  
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY (`parent_id`, `child_validity`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id_child_validity` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`, `child_validity`)
    ->   REFERENCES `parents` (`id`, `parent_validity`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO
    ->   `parents`
    -> VALUES
    ->   (NULL, 1), (NULL, 1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO
    ->   `children`
    -> VALUES
    ->   (NULL, 1, 1),
    ->   (NULL, 1, 1),
    ->   (NULL, 2, 1);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   CONVERT(`parent_validity`, UNSIGNED) `parent_validity`
    -> FROM
    ->   `parents`;
+----+-----------------+
| id | parent_validity |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |               1 |
|  2 |               1 |
+----+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `parent_id`,
    ->   CONVERT(`child_validity`, UNSIGNED) `child_validity`
    -> FROM
    ->   `children`;
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | parent_id | child_validity |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |         1 |              1 |
|  2 |         1 |              1 |
|  3 |         2 |              1 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `parents`
    -> SET `parent_validity` = 0
    -> WHERE `id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   CONVERT(`parent_validity`, UNSIGNED) `parent_validity`
    -> FROM
    ->   `parents`;
+----+-----------------+
| id | parent_validity |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |               0 |
|  2 |               1 |
+----+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `parent_id`,
    ->   CONVERT(`child_validity`, UNSIGNED) `child_validity`
    -> FROM
    ->   `children`;
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | parent_id | child_validity |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |         1 |              0 |
|  2 |         1 |              0 |
|  3 |         2 |              1 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating the constraint 
`CONSTRAINT fk_parent_validity FOREIGN KEY (child_validity)  REFERENCES parents(parent_validity) ON UPDATE CASCADE` creates an new foreign key between your tables.

As you update the `parent_validity` with a value of 1 and change it to 0, MySQL cascades this with the foreign key to set all references where the value was 1 and updates to 0 (in this case all `child_validity` where it originally was 1).

Rather than a foreign key, you need to use an UPDATE trigger. Triggers are additional procedures which automatically run when an event happens on the database. You need an "UPDATE" trigger here.

Think this might work:

`CREATE TRIGGER update_child_validitiy AFTER UPDATE ON parents
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   UPDATE children SET child_validity = NEW.parent_validity WHERE id = NEW.id;
 END;`

I've not used triggers much but hopefully these links help:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html 
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php

Comment: thanks for your valuable information. I wasn't aware of `trigger` concept. I need to read & study it. Can't it be achieved by only using  `constraint`? I only need an update as the original one without any extra operation.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and explain better. The second link seemed easier to follow but i haven't got much experience with MySQL triggers.